QComboBox last highlighted item's corners intersect with the popup's border
I reimplemented QComboBox class and added rounded corners to popup panel:

But when the last item is highlighted, its corners intersect the popup border.

I want to make selection bottom corners round when the last item is highlighted.
I tried to catch QComboBox::highlighted signal like this:
connect(this, 
        SIGNAL(highlighted(int)), 
        this, 
        SLOT(selectionChangedSlot(int)),
        Qt::DirectConnection);

But it didn't work. I can catch other signals like currentIndexChanged, but not highlighted.
What's wrong? Or maybe there's another way to style QComboBox selection this way?
I added a screenshot on other window to show real popup borders:

Header:
#ifndef CUSTOMDROPDOWN_H
#define CUSTOMDROPDOWN_H
#include <QComboBox>
#include "commomColors.h"
#include <QAbstractItemView>
#include <QListView>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QPainterPath>
#include <QPainter>
class customdropdown : public QComboBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit customdropdown(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
protected:
    virtual void showPopup() override;
    virtual void hidePopup() override;
};
class Delegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    virtual void paint( QPainter *, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
};
#endif // CUSTOMDROPDOWN_H

source code:
#include "customdropdown.h"

customdropdown::customdropdown(QWidget *parent) : QComboBox(parent)
{
    this->view()->window()->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint );
    this->view()->window()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    this->setItemDelegate(new Delegate());
    setStyleSheet("QComboBox {"                                 //ComboBox
         "border: 1px solid " RED";"
         "border-radius: 8px;"
         "font-size: 14px;"
         "combobox-popup: 0;"
         "background: transparent;"
         "padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;""}"
   "QComboBox QAbstractItemView {"
          "color: #000000; "
          "background-color: magenta;"
          "border: 1px solid " GREEN";"
          "border-radius: 8px;""}"
    "QListView::item {"
          "height: 26px;""}"
    "QComboBox::down-arrow {"
         "image: url(\":/rsc/img/down_arrow.png\");""}"
    "QComboBox::drop-down:button {"
          "border: 1px solid #FFFFFF"";"
          "border-radius: 8px;"
          "border-left: none;"
          "background-color: transparent;"
          "width: 30px;""}"
    "QComboBox:disabled{"
          "background-color: " DISABLED_BACK_COLOR";"
          "color: " DISABLED_TEXT_COLOR";""}");
}
void customdropdown::showPopup()
{
    setStyleSheet("QComboBox {"                                 //ComboBox
                    "border: 1px solid " RED";"
                    "border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;"
                    "border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;"
                    "border-top-left-radius: 8px;"
                    "border-top-right-radius: 8px;"
                    "font-size: 14px;"
                    "combobox-popup: 0;"
                    "background: transparent;"
                    "padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;""}"
                  "QComboBox QAbstractItemView {"
                    "font-size: 14px;"
                    "border: 1px solid " GREEN";"
                    "border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;"
                    "border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;"
                    "border-top-left-radius: 0px;"
                    "border-top-right-radius: 0px;""}"
                 "QComboBox::down-arrow {"
                    "image: url(\":/rsc/img/down_arrow.png\");""}"
                 "QComboBox::drop-down:button {"
                    "border: 1px solid #FFFFFF"";"
                    "border-radius: 8px;"
                    "border-left: none;"
                    "background-color: transparent;"
                    "width: 30px;""}");
    QListView *view = new QListView(this);
    view->setStyleSheet("QListView::item{"
                        "border: none;"
                        "padding-left: 7px;"
                        "height: 30px;""}"
                        "QListView::item:selected{"
                        "color: #000000;"
                        "background-color: " BLUE";""}");
    this->setView(view);
    QComboBox::showPopup();
}
void customdropdown::hidePopup()
{
    setStyleSheet("QComboBox {"                                 //ComboBox
                    "border: 1px solid " RED";"
                    "border-radius: 8px;"
                    "font-size: 14px;"
                    "combobox-popup: 0;"
                    "background: transparent;"
                    "padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;""}"
                  "QComboBox::down-arrow {"
                    "image: url(\":/rsc/img/down_arrow.png\");""}"
                    "QComboBox::drop-down:button {"
                    "border: 1px solid #FFFFFF"";"
                    "border-radius: 8px;"
                    "border-left: none;"
                    "background-color: transparent;"
                    "width: 30px;""}");
    QComboBox::hidePopup();
}
void Delegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), option.rect.width(), option.rect.height());
    if (index.row() == (index.model()->rowCount()-1))  //if the last item
    {
        path.clear();
        path.addRoundedRect( option.rect, BORDER_RADIUS, BORDER_RADIUS );
        path.addRect( QRect( (option.rect.x()+option.rect.width()-10), option.rect.y(), 10, 10 ) ); // Top right corner not rounded
        path.addRect( QRect( option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), 10, 10 ) ); // TOp left corner not rounded
    }
    painter->save();
    painter->setClipping(true);
    painter->setClipPath(path);
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    painter->restore();
}


You should check the actual shape of the popup, which is most certainly rectangular (as any standard "window" in any system). For future reference, ensure that the bottom of the popup is shown on a darker background, and do more efforts in providing an acceptable screenshot (most imaging tools are able to capture the screen with some delay).

the answer you mentioned didn't help - the borders of popup are correct. I added more screenshots. the problem appears when I hover the last item in list

how can I change  actual shape of the popup?

The borders you see are correct. To what does the gray background belong? Because I'm quite positive that you're setting a palette background role for the parent, which will be inherited by the combo and therefore the popup, so it will look like it's rounded, but it actually isn't. Try to show it overlaid on another background, possibly the desktop or another program, and it will probably show the rectangle mask (the actual shape of the popup). Also, please show how you attempted to apply the suggested solutions in the duplicated posts, and provide environment info (OS/Qt/etc. versions).

this combobox is custom widget, inherited from QComboBox. In this custom comboBox I apply stylesheet, window flags and attributes(from the duplicated post). I added more screenshots on other background. I tried to set itemDelegate like this: this->setItemDelegate(new Delegate()), but nothing changed. Delegate code is listed above. I use Qt 5.15.3,Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

You're again showing the popup against a white background which can not show the actual geometry of the popup. I suggest you to provide all the relevant code in form of a [mre]. Note that setting the clipping in the delegate is most certainly useless, as the style will probably override it; also, you are not restoring the state of the painter (since that code is commented), which is wrong, and even assuming that the style doesn't change clipping, restore() should be called after making the call to the super class function.

I added one more screenshot and it seems that the actual geometry of popup is not rounded, but I don't know how to change it. I also added source code so can you please have a look? I'm really stuck with this question
